# Meaning of "hay-trusser"

Tags: dialects

I am not a native speaker of English and would like to know the meaning of this word "hay-trusser". I am doing a Translation Study from Thomas Hardy's The Mayor of Casterbridge for Universidad Menéndez-Pelayo in Spain and I am not familiar with this terminoloy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's someone who makes up trusses (bundles) of hay

[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss_(unit))

> the standard weights of a truss were:
>   new hay, 60 pounds
>   old hay, 56 pounds
>   straw, 36 pounds
>
> and 36 trusses made up a load.

A more detailed description of the actions of trussing can be seen at the Wikipedia link above (there's too much there to quote in an answer here).

Comment: I found also the information in Yahoo, but I could't post it here. Your answer was great and fast.

Comment: Americans _bale_ hay. This usage seems to be limited to Britain.

Comment: @KarlG I worked on farms in Scotland as a schoolboy in the 1960s and we called it hay-baling then. 'Truss' is very archaic.

Comment: Sounds like something out of Thomas Hardy to me.

Comment: You are right, Kate Bunting.